# How to pass query params of a request url while mocking with Request Hooks in Testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, mocking, automated-tests, testcafe

My request url has multiple query params. I want to mock the response of the external API while writing my tests in Testcafe. I want to mock the data in E2E testing because my data will expire in every 15days.
Please suggest some ways to handle mocking the request with query param. I am able to mock the request not having any query param and I am using Request Hooks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a difference between a mocking response from URL with parameters and without them. You can mock a response by using [`RequestMock`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#mock-http-requests) API:

```js
...
const getDataMock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(/.*getData\?param=param_1/)
    .respond((req, res) => {
        res.setBody({...});
    });
...
```

If this doesn't work for you, please provide us with the code where you define `RequestMock` or `RequestHook`.

Comment: Thanks :) For some reason that was not working but I tried again after seeing your comments and it worked.