# Testcafe mock request/response with query parameters

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to mock a response for a request that uses query params. I've already used [onrequestto](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto) in other tests, and it works seamlessly. There is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382355/how-to-pass-query-params-of-a-request-url-while-mocking-with-request-hooks-in-te) to what I am asking, but the answer does not work for me whatever I do :(

The request that my frontend makes to get data from backend is something like

```
https://fake.com/search?Status=authorised&SortBy=Order
```

what I do in my tests is:

```
import {RequestMock} from "testcafe";
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo('\/search\?Status=authorised')
    .respond({data:ok}, 200, {'content-type': 'application/json charset=utf-8'})


fixture('Test suite')
    .page('fake.com')
    .requestHooks(mock);
```

and proceed with my .test. Neither OPTIONS nor GET requests return the data that I am expecting. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @aleks-pro can you please help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

`onRequestTo` Should receive Regex value. So you have to change it to `onRequestTo(/\/search\?Status=authorised/)`.

See https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto

Comment: in the link that you provided the first example is
```.onRequestTo('http://external-service.com/api/')```
why can't I use the same exact match as they use in docs?

Comment: In the example they provide whole URL. In your case, you want to match the request just by the part of the URL.